# NHibernate - How to Enable Logging to Debug an Issue

Tags: nhibernate

I have a weird issue when committing changes in NHibernate.  It doesn't throw an error but only about 20% of the time the changes are committed to the database.  I know it sounds like a strange question and without code you won't be able to help much but i was just wondering what's the best way to debug this.

I've tried SQL Server Profile but this did not help much. Is there a way to enable logging or intercept any queries in NHibernate.

I'd really appreciate your advice.  Thanks

Comment: I am have a similar problem. Can you please share what you found from the logging.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Bofors my problem was quite specific to my application. Also i can't remember the exact problem so i won't be able to help sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any other details, all I can recommend is to [enable logging](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.aspx) and/or use [nhprof](http://www.nhprof.com/) to diagnose it.